# Is there any way to get history of the command issued in microstrategy command manager on perticular date?

Tags: microstrategy

I would like get all the commands issued using microstrategy on a given date. Can some one please tell me how will I be able to fetch this information. Is there any log file to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

There is a log in Command Manager but it is not enabled by default.  To enable this, follow steps:

1. Login to Command Manager
2. Go to Tools drop-down
3. Select Options...
4. Select the Log tab
5. Enable "Use File Logging"
6. Specify log file locations

If this is enabled already then just check the log file in the location that is listed in that tab.